# Push activerecord change from rails to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, push

I have a client javascript client app that pulls data from my rails app. The data(activerecord) is susceptible to changes. I want to push the changes back to my javascript client. For example in after_commit.

I've read into  the faye-websocket-ruby gem. This seems like what I need, but I'm  not sure I know how to use it.

https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby/blob/master/README.md

Their example of implementing the server:

```
require 'faye/websocket'

App = lambda do |env|
  if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
    ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env)

    ws.on :message do |event|
      ws.send(event.data)
    end

    ws.on :close do |event|
      p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
      ws = nil
    end

    # Return async Rack response
    ws.rack_response

  else
    # Normal HTTP request
    [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ['Hello']]
  end
end
```

I'm mostly confused about this part:

```
ws.on :message do |event|
      ws.send(event.data)
    end
```

Because I don't want to receive data here, I want to send data on change and receive it in my javascript client.

So basically I would like to call ws.send in my models after_commit callback.

How do I do that?